# Flutter - Hot reload isn't working on Vivo Y22 (Android 13)

Tags: flutter, debugging

I'm encountering an issue with Flutter's hot reload feature and debugging on my Android 13 device. After updating the Vivo Y22 phone's operating system to Android 13, I noticed that the hot reload feature stopped working. I can run the app using 'flutter run' command but I'm unable to debug my app as 'run' prompt is also not available. Interestingly, all other devices running Android 12 work perfectly fine with hot reload and debugging. I've already run `flutter doctor` and it hasn't identified any issues. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this problem.

Tried 'flutter clean' command
Tried restarting Android studio, phone, PC.
Disabled and re-enabled developer mode and developer settings.
Uninstalled existing apk.
Cleared data and cache and uninstalled existing apk.

Comment: If you updated the android studio flutter plugin check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77389010/2831595