# Flutter hot reload is not working in Android Studio Physical Device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

While using flutter on android studio using **physical device** via USB debugging, **Flutter hot reload** is not working. It needs to run from start each time after making changes.
The icon of  is dimmed even if my application is on running state.

Does Hot reload works with physical devices?

Comment: _Either a physical or virtual device can be the target._ https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/hot-reload

Comment: I used flutter run, but hot reload is still inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

The flutter plugin is broken the Hot Reload on the last update, I spent some time to make it work, backing to and older version.

To me the version 76.1.x is broken, so i download the earlier one 76.0.x and it works fine.

You can download the old versions here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions

I did filled a issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7027

[image: flutter plugin version]

After downloading you can install on the guear icon on the plugins page and select install plugin from disk:

[image: Install plugin from disc]

Comment: I have found that the version I am having supports hot reload in devices other than ViVo phones. This is weird because I have checked it on many Vivo phones none of them supports hot reload.